# UBUNTU KVM bridge problem

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, network-bridge

I'm going crazy with a bridge problem on KVM.
I had an Ubuntu 22.10 server with KVM hosting a bridged host that got an IP from the same network as the host.
After updating to UBUNTU 23.04 it doesn't work anymore.
Who can help me ?

```
**ifconfig**
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::244e:18ff:fed6:b629  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:4e:18:d6:b6:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6883389  bytes 9894516783 (9.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 279  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4085716  bytes 2144786872 (2.1 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 44:1e:a1:3b:78:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9583280  bytes 10215881814 (10.2 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5077805  bytes 2230623200 (2.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:0d:bc:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33412  bytes 4982419 (4.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28802  bytes 14846506 (14.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

**brctl show**
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-4becbc5f00c4         8000.02421d943049       no
br-91f699252029         8000.0242a8b934e2       no
br-e638cb326bd4         8000.02429d009cae       no
br0                     8000.264e18d6b629       no              enp2s0
                                                                vnet4
docker0                 8000.0242fc1f43fe       no
virbr0                  8000.5254000dbc93       yes

**ip route**
default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0 proto static
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-91f699252029 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-e638cb326bd4 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-4becbc5f00c4 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

**HOST ON KVM**
root@homeassistant:—# ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default glen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: ens1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default glen 1000 link/ether 52:54:00:9c:c6:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff altname enp2sl inet6 fe80::a07f:b2a7:2716:d1f8/64 scope link noprefixroute valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```